# Swift Speech Recognition - Pause so response can be read back to user

Tags: swift, speech-recognition, avspeechsynthesizer

I am using speech recognition for input from the user and I want to read the result back to the user using AVSpeechSynthesizer as a verification.  The problem is that when the speech is read back the Speech Recognition reads it again.  I'm trying to find a way to pause speech recognition after it reads a specific phrase so the synthesizer can read it back.

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing it is to use voice activity detector. Basically, this library, stops recording once silence is detected. Make this as a conditional statement, if satisfied continue executing subset tasks. If you could share more details, it'll help.

Comment: What I really need is a way to stop recognition manually once I receive a valid response so I can read it back to the user.

Comment: Have you tried using a key or button. Something like if keyboard.read_key() == "q": followed by break.